# PHPExcel: using "getHighestRow" in combination with read filter

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm currently using PHPExcel to read an excel file in chunks using a read filter, as the spreadsheet has the potential to become large in the future, and I need to ensure that enough memory will remain free to handle it regardless of size.

As part of the logic, I want to retrieve the number of rows in the sheet, which I'm aware can be done as follows:

```php
$file = 'path/to/spreadsheet.xslx';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
return $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
```

My question is, is doing this going to cause PHP to run out of memory if the file is too large?

i.e. in the same way that it would if I used the following with a large file:

```php
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->tooArray();
```

And if so, is there a way of retrieving the the highest row without causing a memory problem when the file becomes large?

I've tested this up as far as a 3MB file on my local machine, and it seems to cope fine, except takes and increasingly long time to return the highest row the bigger the file is.

Comment: Not sure if there is an alternative to do such, perhaps check the iterators in the PHPExcel libraries and try to make it lighter for your case? Not sure if it will change much anyway, it's such an heavy elaboration in any case :)

Comment: Cool, will do, thanks for the response :). As this is for a command line tool, I might end up just resorting to manually specifying the number of rows as an argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the number of rows (or columns) in a worksheet without loading the whole file:

```
$file = 'path/to/spreadsheet.xslx';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($file);

echo '<h3>Worksheet Information</h3>';
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($worksheetData as $worksheet) {
    echo '<li>', $worksheet['worksheetName'], '<br />';
    echo 'Rows: ', $worksheet['totalRows'], 
        ' Columns: ', $worksheet['totalColumns'], '<br />';
    echo 'Cell Range: A1:', 
        $worksheet['lastColumnLetter'], $worksheet['totalRows'];
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

As shown in section 7 (`Helper Methods`) of the `PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files`

Comment: Aha, brilliant, I did wonder if there was some way of doing it with metadata that I hadn't come across. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Is there any way to tag Mark Baker in any question concerning PHPexcel? :P

Comment: @MarkBaker And if I need to count unique rows (by certain column), how can I achieve that efficiently? Lets say to get total number of unique values for the column named "User Name" ? Ignoring duplicates

Comment: @Andrew `$uniqueCount = count(array_unique(array_column($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('D1:D100'), 0)));` as  long as you know which column has your User Name, and how many total rows